# Dynamically adding elements in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**tl;dr**: I am generating a table with editable cells similar to the one pictured below.  I have it so the cells are editable and the total updates, but I am struggling to figure out the process I need to follow to actually add new rows and columns.

[image]

All of the cells with the exception of total are editable by the end user, for example cell[ex1][item1] can be changed from 100 to 150, which then causes an event that will update that total for that row from 320 to 370.

Initially I define the main template in the HTML file...

```
<div class="container" id="app">

    <script type="text/x-template" id="datagrid-template">
        <table class="table-striped">
            <thead>
                <headerrow v-bind:columns="columns"></headerrow>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <datarow v-for="row in rows" v-bind:columns="columns" v-bind:data="row"></datarow>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <datagrid v-bind:columns="columns" v-bind:data="rows"></datagrid>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" v-on:click="addColumn()">Add Column</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" v-on:click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the JS file I init the main Vue element as such...

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    categories: [...],
    companies: [...]
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function() {
      console.log(this.$children[0]);
    },
    addColumn: function() {
      this.$children[0].columns.push({value: 'test'});
    }
  }
});
```

I then have 6 main different component types:

- datainput (general input cell)
- dataheader (extends datainput)
- datacell (extends datainput)
- baserow (row in the tables)
- headerrow (extends baserow, composed of dataheaders)
- datarow (extends baserow, composed of datacells)

I add a row and the cells through as such

**baserow**

```
var baseRow = {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('tr', {}, this.getProps(createElement));
  },
  props: {...}
  }
};
```

**headerrow**

```
Vue.component('headerrow', {
  mixins: [baseRow],
  methods: {
    getProps: function(createElement) {
      var comps = [];
      this.$options.propsData.columns.forEach(function(el) {
        comps.push(createElement('dataheader', {
          props: {...}
        }));
      });
      return comps;
    }
  }
});
```

When I click add column I can see the 'test' get added to the columns prop when viewing the `<datagrid>` using the chrome extension.  Additionally, I see the 'test' get added to the `<headerrow>` columns prop, but nothing in the UI is ever actually generated.  I am assuming that this is a result of how I initially render the rows and columns, and that I am just having some sort of fundamental misunderstanding... Could anyone provide some direction as to far as what and where I go wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So it was a fundamental misunderstanding.  To accomplish this the data must be used in conjunction with the props.  Initially the values must be attached as a prop and then the prop should then be assigned to a data value.  The following example highlights what I was trying to do.

```
var baseRow = {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('tr', this.createCells(createElement));
  },
  props: {
    initColumns: {
      type: Array,
      default: []
    },
    initData: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      columns: this.initColumns,
      data: this.initData
    }
  }
};
```

Then to add an element, from the main Vue object (that contains the row component) you can call something similar to `this.columns.push({value: 'test'});`.  This will update the columns data attribute and will also update the UI.

From my understanding this is a result of the props having a [one-way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow), while the data property is reactive, which is disucessed in [this section of the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can't use anything other than a `<tr>` within a `<tbody>`.  You can use the Vue directive `is` to add other components there:

```
<tbody>
    <tr is="datarow" v-for="row in rows" v-bind:columns="columns" v-bind:data="row"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but datarow is a tr.  Look at the baserow section of my question, I render it via createElement('tr', {}, this.getProps(createElement));.

Comment: datarow is a `<tr>` AFTER Vue parses the template and builds it.  the DOM throws out anything inside a `<tbody>` that isn't a `<tr>` before that even happens.  The same issue will arise with `<td>` inside the `<tr>`

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats It makes it sounds as though the template inside <script type="text/x-template"> is exempt from this.  Additionally, changing it to tr, td, th don't seem to do the trick.  The issue is still that the <dataheader> is never generated and added to the <headerrow>.

Comment: Ah I see.  I was not aware this was avoided using the script tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though, do you have any ideas as to why the element is never added to the tree shown in my last screenshot? You can see that it is added to the data object and then the prop object, but it never is rendered in the UI.